# C++ getaddrinfo() wrapper

Tags: c++, networking, unix

**EDIT**: New version can be found here: [C++ getaddrinfo()/addrinfo wrapper (rewrite)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135751)

I'm a C++ novice, but an experienced Python and C programmer. I decided to code a C++ wrapper around `getaddrinfo()` to get my feet wet (targeted at Unix, specifically). Am I using good style/best practises? How can I improve this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>
#include <utility>
#include <cerrno>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>


class GetAddrInfo
{
private:
        addrinfo *result;
        const addrinfo hints;
public:
        const std::string node;
        const std::string service;

        explicit GetAddrInfo(const std::string &node_,
                const std::string &service_, const addrinfo &hints_) :
                hints(hints_), node(node_), service(service_)
        {
                int res = getaddrinfo(node.c_str(), service.c_str(),
                        &hints, &result);
                if(res != 0)
                        throw std::system_error(res, std::generic_category(),
                                gai_strerror(res));
        }

        GetAddrInfo(GetAddrInfo &&other) :
                result(std::move(other.result)), hints(std::move(other.hints)),
                node(std::move(other.node)), service(std::move(other.service))
        {
                // The other object's dead
                other.result = nullptr;
        }

        GetAddrInfo(const GetAddrInfo &other) :
                GetAddrInfo(other.node, other.service, other.hints) {}

        ~GetAddrInfo()
        {
                if(result != nullptr)
                        freeaddrinfo(result);
        }

        class iterator
        {
        private:
                addrinfo *rp;
        public:
                using self_type = iterator;
                using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
                using value_type = addrinfo;
                using pointer = addrinfo *;
                using reference = addrinfo &;
                using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

                bool operator==(self_type &other) const
                {
                        return rp == other.rp;
                }

                bool operator!=(self_type &other) const
                {
                        return rp != other.rp;
                }

                self_type operator=(const self_type &other)
                {
                        rp = other.rp;
                        return *this;
                }

                self_type operator++()
                {
                        self_type ret = *this;
                        if(rp != NULL)
                                rp = rp->ai_next;

                        return ret;
                }

                self_type operator++(int)
                {
                        if(rp != NULL)
                                rp = rp->ai_next;

                        return *this;
                }

                value_type & operator*()
                {
                        return *rp;
                }

                value_type * operator->()
                {
                        return rp;
                }

                iterator(addrinfo *rp) : rp(rp) {}
                iterator() = default;
        };

        class const_iterator
        {
        private:
                addrinfo *rp;
        public:
                using self_type = const_iterator;
                using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
                using value_type = addrinfo;
                using pointer = addrinfo *;
                using reference = addrinfo &;
                using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

                bool operator==(self_type &other) const
                {
                        return rp == other.rp;
                }

                bool operator!=(self_type &other) const
                {
                        return rp != other.rp;
                }

                self_type operator=(const self_type &other)
                {
                        rp = other.rp; return *this;
                }

                self_type operator++()
                {
                        self_type ret = *this;
                        if(rp != NULL)
                                rp = rp->ai_next;

                        return ret;
                }

                self_type operator++(int)
                {
                        if(rp != NULL)
                                rp = rp->ai_next;

                        return *this;
                }

                const value_type & operator*()
                {
                        return *rp;
                }

                const value_type * operator->()
                {
                        return rp;
                }

                const_iterator(addrinfo *rp) : rp(rp) {}
                const_iterator() = default;
        };

        iterator begin() { return iterator(result); }
        iterator end() { return iterator(NULL); }
        const_iterator cbegin() { return const_iterator(result); }
        const_iterator cend() { return const_iterator(NULL); }

        template <template <typename...> class T>
        T<addrinfo> to_container()
        {
                T<addrinfo> container;
                std::copy(begin(), end(), container.begin());
                return container;
        }

        using container_pair = std::pair<int, std::string>;

        template <template <typename...> class T>
        T<container_pair> to_container_pair()
        {
                T<container_pair> container;

                for(addrinfo *rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next)
                {
                        char str_addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {};
                        void *sock_ptr;

                        if(rp->ai_family == AF_INET)
                                sock_ptr = &(((sockaddr_in *)rp->ai_addr)->
                                        sin_addr);
                        else
                                sock_ptr = &(((sockaddr_in6 *)rp->ai_addr)->
                                        sin6_addr);

                        inet_ntop(rp->ai_family, sock_ptr, str_addr,
                                sizeof(str_addr));
                        container.push_back(std::make_pair(rp->ai_family,
                                std::string(str_addr)));
                }

                return container;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Operators

You don't need to override `operator=` in the iterator - the default will do what you want just fine. In general, remember the [rules of 3, 5, and 0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  This also means that you need to implement the copy and move assignment operators for your `AddressInfo` class. I'd also recommend adding an explicit conversion to and from an `addrinfo*` so users of the library can still interface with raw uses of it.

Your copy constructor should absolutely not call the parameterized constructor - `getaddrinfo` is usually an expensive call, and it'll be much cheaper to just copy the `addrinfo*` manually.

Your `operator++` shouldn't do any bounds checking - its the caller's job to make sure that incrementing is a valid operation.

#### Iterator

Your iterator can be templated on the type so that you can then do

```
template <typename T>
struct Iterator { ... };

using iterator = Iterator<addrinfo>;
using const_iterator = Iterator<const addrinfo>;
```

You make some weird choices in your operator overloading and implementation of your operators (as mentioned above).  You can just specify all constructors as default as well.  I'd make it a struct instead of a class, but that's just personal preference.

#### Interface

You add some weird member functions that I don't think add any value - `to_container` and `to_container_pair`. If a user wants to convert your thing to some other container, they already have the ability to do so. `to_container` adds very little value.

`to_container_pair` adds a bit more value (it does quite a bit more work), but there are a few criticisms I have for it.

You implemented your iterator but you aren't using it - that's silly.  You also are doing too much in this function. I'd pull out getting the socket pointer to a function, and getting the ip address to another function.  Then you can do it in a more iterator based way.

```
template <template <typename...> class T>
T<container_pair> to_container_pair()
{
    T<container_pair> container;

    std::transform(begin(), end(), std::back_inserter(container), 
      [](const addrinfo& address) {
        return std::make_pair(address.ai_family, getIpAddress(address));
      });

    return container;
}

std::string getIpAddress(const addrinfo& address)
{
    char str_addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    void* sock_ptr = getSocketPointer(address);
    inet_ntop(address.ai_family, sock_ptr, str_addr, sizeof(str_addr));
    return std::string(str_addr);    
}

void* getSocketPointer(const addrinfo& address)
{
    if (address.ai_family == AF_INET)
    {
        return &(static_cast<sockaddr_in*>(address.ai_addr)->sin_addr);
    } 
    else
    {
        return &(static_cast<sockaddr_in6*>(address.ai_addr)->sin6_addr);
    }    
}
```

#### Move construction

For primitives you generally don't need to move them - they fit into registers and are essentially free to copy.  Thus you don't need to move `result`.

#### Names/types

In C++ we generally call a pointer to something a `T* p` and not `T *p` - the second version is a C thing. You can also benefit by using much more expressive names - `result` becomes `addresses`, `rp` becomes `current` or `currentAddress`, etc.

The name `GetAddrInfo` isn't really how you want to name a class. You could name a function like that, but the class is really just the address information. You could call it `AddrInfo`, but there isn't any value to dropping three characters, so `AddressInfo` is probably best.

#### `addrinfo*`

Lastly, I'd consider making a wrapper struct to encapsulate an `addrinfo` - instead of directly exposing that to a user, who could then mess with the pointers and stuff, give them a struct to use. This can also have better names, because while the names used have been around forever, they're not always descriptive and are a pain to use.  If they want access to the raw `addrinfo*` then they should use the explicit conversion operator you give them.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think to make the iterator class a template to avoid duplication. I think I actually saw the iterator code boilerplate somewhere and copied it.

Comment: If I make the suggested changes to the code, should I edit the original to have the new code?

Comment: @ElizabethMyers no - you should ask a new question if you want further review on the updated code, but don't update the code in a question after an answer has been given.

Answer (score 3):

#### Define Similar operators in terms of each other.

```
                bool operator!=(self_type &other) const
                {
                        return rp != other.rp;
                }
```

If your code ever changes you want to writ it in a way that allows you to update the code with the minimal number of changes. This means writting function in terms of each other. In this case write the `operator!=()` in terms of the `operator==()`. Thus if there is a change in the code you only need to update one function.

```
                bool operator!=(self_type &other) const
                {
                        return !(*this) == other;
                }
```

#### Be consistent and prefer `nullptr`

You have used `nullptr` in the code. But here you use `NULL` here.

```
                        if(rp != NULL)
                                rp = rp->ai_next;
```

#### You have your pre-fix and postfix operators the wrong way around.

This is the pre-fix version.

```
                self_type operator++()
```

This should modify and immediately return the changed value. Since you have modified the current value you can return the value as reference rather than generating a copy.

This is the post-fix version.

```
                self_type operator++(int)
```

This should return the original value but modify modify the underlying object. This means making a copy. But like the `operator!=()` you should define this method in terms of the prefix value.

```
                self_type& operator++()
                {
                    if(rp != NULL)
                    {
                        rp = rp->ai_next;
                    }

                    return *this;
                }

                self_type operator++(int)
                {
                    self_type result {*this};
                    ++(*this);
                    return result;
                }
```

#### Use the typedef's

```
                value_type & operator*()    
                value_type * operator->()
```

You already have specific types defined at the top of the class for these return values.

```
                using pointer = addrinfo *;
                using reference = addrinfo &;
```

#### iterator Vs const_iterator

There is a lot of repeated code here. There are a couple of ways to solve this but basically you can put put the common code into a single class and then the different code is done separately.

#### Iterator creation.

```
        iterator begin() { return iterator(result); }
        iterator end() { return iterator(NULL); }
```

You should also have a `begin()` and `end()` that will work on a const object.

```
        const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(result); }
        const_iterator end()   const { return const_iterator(NULL); }
```

The const iterator creation methods should be marked as const.

```
        const_iterator cbegin() const { return const_iterator(result); }
        const_iterator cend()   const { return const_iterator(NULL); }
                          ///   ^^^^^
```

#### Don't add extraneous functions.

```
        template <template <typename...> class T>
        T<addrinfo> to_container()
        {
                T<addrinfo> container;
                std::copy(begin(), end(), container.begin());
                return container;
        }
```

Don't see the need for this.

```
        std::vector<addrinfo>  x = d.to_container()

        // or

        std::vector<addrinfo>  x(d.begin(), d.end());
```

Comment: Thank you! Very useful feedback. I noticed a lot of these things were things I noticed, but never got around to fixing because they "looked ok" to my C-trained eyes. I'll need to get into the C++ run of things. :P

Comment: Is it defined that `NULL` will equal `nullptr` in C++?

Comment: @Dannnno: Its not the same thing though. Because `nullptr` has a type of `std::nullptr_t`.

Comment: I know, I was just curious if (in)equality works as you'd expect though, and if that were guaranteed by the standard or just an implementation detail of most compilers

Comment: @Dannnno: nullptr_t is not convertible to int. int is not convertible nullptr_t. Any attempt to compare the two would be a compiler error.