# C++ getaddrinfo()/addrinfo wrapper (rewrite)

Tags: c++, c++14, networking, unix

As suggested by @Dannnno on [my original post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135708/c-getaddrinfo-wrapper), I am posting my partially rewritten `getaddrinfo()` (and now `addrinfo`) wrapper for merciless review. I've made quite a few changes to the code as suggested originally, and included a minimal example of `main()` to show how it comes together.

Some things I'd like to note:

- I decided not to expose a `next` method in my AddrInfo wrapper for now, since it's only used for `getaddrinfo()` results. I thought about making the iterator built into the `AddrInfo` class instead of `GetAddrInfo`, but decided against it.
- I'm not sure if I did my assignment operators correctly in `getaddrinfo()`, or if there's even a better approach to writing them (I am not entirely happy with the duplication of code).
- I've targeted this at Unix for now, but I'm open to fixes for portability to Windows and the like (but not necessarily asking for them).

**EDIT**: Incorporated some changes suggested to the original, but it doesn't change the underlying code substantially.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>
#include <utility>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>


class AddrInfo
{
private:
    struct addrinfo *next_;
public:
    int flags = 0;
    int addr_family = 0;
    int socket_type = 0;
    int protocol = 0;
    socklen_t address_len = 0;
    sockaddr *address = nullptr;
    char *canonical_name = nullptr;

    const addrinfo to_addrinfo()
    {
        addrinfo addr = {};

        addr.ai_flags = flags;
        addr.ai_family = addr_family;
        addr.ai_socktype = socket_type;
        addr.ai_protocol = protocol;
        addr.ai_addrlen = address_len;
        addr.ai_addr = address;
        addr.ai_canonname = canonical_name;
        addr.ai_next = next_;

        return addr;
    }

    std::pair<int, std::string> to_pair()
    {
        char str_addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {};
        void *sock_ptr;

        if(addr_family == AF_INET)
            sock_ptr = &(((sockaddr_in *)address)->sin_addr);
        else
            sock_ptr = &(((sockaddr_in6 *)address)->sin6_addr);

        inet_ntop(addr_family, sock_ptr, str_addr, sizeof(str_addr));

        return std::make_pair(addr_family, std::string(str_addr));
    }

    AddrInfo(struct addrinfo &ai) :
        next_(ai.ai_next), flags(ai.ai_flags),
        addr_family(ai.ai_family), socket_type(ai.ai_socktype),
        protocol(ai.ai_protocol), address_len(ai.ai_addrlen),
        address(ai.ai_addr), canonical_name(ai.ai_canonname)
    {}
    AddrInfo(struct addrinfo *ai) : AddrInfo(*ai) {}
    AddrInfo() = default;
};

class GetAddrInfo
{
private:
    addrinfo *result;
    addrinfo hints;

    inline void do_getaddrinfo()
    {
        int res = getaddrinfo(node.c_str(), service.c_str(),
            &hints, &result);
        if(res != 0)
            throw std::system_error(res, std::generic_category(),
                gai_strerror(res));
    }
public:
    std::string node;
    std::string service;

    explicit GetAddrInfo(const std::string &node,
        const std::string &service, const addrinfo &hints) :
        hints(hints), node(node), service(service)
    {
        do_getaddrinfo();
    }

    explicit GetAddrInfo(const std::string &node,
        const std::string &service, AddrInfo &hints) :
        GetAddrInfo(node, service, hints.to_addrinfo()) {}

    GetAddrInfo(GetAddrInfo &&other) :
        result(other.result), hints(std::move(other.hints)),
        node(std::move(other.node)), service(std::move(other.service))
    {
        // The other object's dead
        other.result = nullptr;
    }

    GetAddrInfo(const GetAddrInfo &other) :
        GetAddrInfo(other.node, other.service, other.hints) {}

    ~GetAddrInfo()
    {
        if(result != nullptr)
            freeaddrinfo(result);
    }

    GetAddrInfo & operator=(const GetAddrInfo &other)
    {
        if(result != nullptr)
            freeaddrinfo(result);

        node = other.node;
        service = other.service;
        hints = other.hints;

        do_getaddrinfo();
        return *this;
    }

    GetAddrInfo & operator=(GetAddrInfo &&other)
    {
        if(other.result != nullptr)
        {
            freeaddrinfo(other.result);
            other.result = nullptr;
        }

        node = std::move(other.node);
        service = std::move(other.service);
        hints = std::move(other.hints);

        do_getaddrinfo();
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    class Iterator
    {
    private:
        addrinfo *addr;
        AddrInfo cur; // A temporary to hold a reference
    public:
        using self_type = Iterator<T>;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T *;
        using reference = T &;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

        bool operator==(self_type &other) const
        {
            return addr == other.addr;
        }

        bool operator!=(self_type &other) const
        {
            return addr != other.addr;
        }

        self_type & operator++()
        {
            addr = addr->ai_next;
            return *this;
        }

        self_type operator++(int)
        {
            self_type &ret = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return ret;
        }

        reference operator*()
        {
            cur = AddrInfo(addr);
            return cur;
        }

        Iterator(addrinfo *addr) : addr(addr) {}
    };

    using iterator = Iterator<AddrInfo>;
    using const_iterator = Iterator<const AddrInfo>;

    iterator begin() { return iterator(result); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(nullptr); }
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return const_iterator(result); }
    const_iterator cend() const { return const_iterator(nullptr); }
};


int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid number of arguments" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " host [host]..."
            << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    AddrInfo hints;
    hints.addr_family = AF_UNSPEC;

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            GetAddrInfo addr(argv[i], "", hints);

            std::cout << "Results for " << argv[i] << ':' << std::endl;

            for(auto &result : addr)
            {
                auto res = result.to_pair();
                std::cout << (res.first == AF_INET ? "IPv4" : "IPv6") << ": ";
                std::cout << res.second << std::endl;
            }
        }
        catch(std::system_error &e)
        {
            std::cerr << "Could not resolve " << argv[i] << ": "
                << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: At first glance, it looks as if you have your iterator's pre-increment and post-increment swapped with each other (`operator++(int)` should be post-increment, which yields the previous value, and `operator++()` should be the pre-increment, which yields the incremented value).

Comment: You have a bug, your `operator=` will make you sad if you're doing self-assignment, i.e. `GetAddrInfo a(args...); a = a`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that `GetAddrInfo` is sort of a class without a cause, so to speak. Essentially all it really does is handle the mechanics of its own existence--initial creation, copy construction, move construction, assignment, etc. Essentially the only things you can really do with a `GetAddrInfo` are call its `begin` and `end` (or `cbegin`/`cend`) to get iterators into an underlying sequence.

I'd rather get rid of the `GetAddrInfo` object, and just create iterators directly.

In somewhat simplified form, the idea could look something like this:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

class IP_user {
    WSADATA d;
public:
    IP_user() {
        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &d);
    }

    ~IP_user() {
        WSACleanup();
    }
} init; 

#else
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif

namespace addr {
    using T = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;

    class iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T> {
        struct addrinfo *start;
        struct addrinfo *address;
public:

        iterator(std::string const &node_name, std::string const &service_name = "", addrinfo *hints = nullptr) {
            getaddrinfo(node_name.c_str(), service_name.c_str(), hints, &address);
            start = address;
        }

        iterator() : start(nullptr), address(nullptr) { }

        iterator(iterator &&other) 
            : start(other.start), 
            address(other.address) 
        {
            other.start = nullptr;
        }

        iterator operator=(iterator &&other) = delete;
        iterator(iterator const &other) = delete;
        iterator operator=(iterator const &other) = delete;

        iterator &operator++() {
            address = address->ai_next;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator == (iterator const &other) { 
            return address == other.address;
        }

        bool operator !=(iterator const &other) { 
            return address != other.address;
        }

        T operator*() const { 
            static const std::map<int, std::string> names{
                { AF_INET, "IPv4" },
                { AF_INET6, "IPv6" }
            };

            char str_addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {};       

            std::string res;
            if (address->ai_family == AF_INET)
                res = inet_ntoa(((sockaddr_in *)address->ai_addr)->sin_addr);
            else
                res = inet_ntop(address->ai_family, address->ai_addr, str_addr, sizeof(str_addr));

            return std::make_pair(names.find(address->ai_family)->second, std::string(res));
        }

        ~iterator() { 
            if (start != nullptr)
                freeaddrinfo(start); 
        }
    };
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    for (addr::iterator b(argv[1]), e; b != e; ++b)
        std::cout << (*b).first << ": " << (*b).second << "\n";
}
```